# XML configuration of object attributes in Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

I spent a few days working through tutorials on using the XML configuration injection method, in Spring, and embarking on my first attempt to apply it. The tutorials applied to simple examples. My project is a bit more involved.
This is the scenario: I am passing an object, ReadTLEFileRequest, containing the filepath to the file to be read, into a ReadTLEFile class (implemented through the interface class). ReadTLEFile is where the file gets processed etc.

```
package useCases;
import java.io.IOException;
public interface IReadTLEFile {

    public ReadTLEFileResult readFile(ReadTLEFileRequest object)
            throws IOException, FileEmptyException,
            FileIncorrectFormatException, FileIncorrectDataException;
}

package useCases;
public class ReadTLEFileRequest {

    String filepath;

    public ReadTLEFileRequest(String filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        return filepath;
    }
}
```

The main method currently looks like this (and executes without problem):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String filepath = "TLE files/geostationary.txt";
ReadTLEFileRequest request = new ReadTLEFileRequest(filepath);
IReadTLEFile reader = new ReadTLEFile(request);
try {
        reader.readFile(request);
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I would like to use dependency injection so I am thinking the main method needs to be modified to become something like this:

```
AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
try{              
    ReadTLEFileRequest object = (ReadTLEFileRequest) context.getBean("requestObject");
    object.readFile(request);
    }
    finally{
        context.close();
    }
```

The Beans.xml file contains

```
<bean id="requestFile" class="useCases/ReadTLEFileRequest">
    <property name="requestObject">
        <bean id="requestObject" class="useCases/ReadTLEFileRequest"></property>
</bean>
```

Essentially, the question is this: how to correctly construct the XML bean configuration for an object with properties, and how to instantiate the IoC for this particular case.

Answer (score -1):

Your configuration might some what be like this

```
<br>
package useCases;
import java.io.IOException;
public interface IReadTLEFile {
public ReadTLEFileResult readFile(ReadTLEFileRequest object)throws IOException, FileEmptyException,FileIncorrectFormatException, FileIncorrectDataException;
}
```

```
package useCases;
public class ReadTLEFileRequest {

    String filepath;

    public ReadTLEFileRequest(String filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        return filepath;
    }
}
```

```
package useCases;
class ReadTLEFile implements IReadTLEFile{
   private ReadTLEFileRequest request;

   public void setRequest(ReadTLEFileRequest request){
     this.request = request;
   } 
}
```

```
<bean id="requestFile" class="useCases.ReadTLEFile">
   <property name="request"><ref bean = "requestObject"/></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="requestObject" class="useCases.ReadTLEFileRequest">
         <property name = "filepath"><value>TLE files/geostationary.txt</value></property>
    </property>
```

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
    IReadTLEFile object =  context.getBean("requestObject",ReadTLEFile.class);
    object.readFile();
```

Comment: Your solution is not correct. filepath is a String object not a bean, so you should not declare a bean with that name and put it as reference.
Also, if you have a dependency from within ReadTLEFile object to the request object, and the dependency is injected with the proper configuration, why do you need to call object.readFile with a parameter that is already injected in the object attribute?

Comment: You can add the filepath bean class attribute as class = "java.lang.String". <bean id = "filepath" class = "java.lang.String" ><value>TLE files/geostationary.txt</value></property></bean>

Comment: The feedback helped. Thank you. Still getting error messages I can't resolve. The code lives here:https://github.com/Carla-de-Beer/Java/tree/master/DI%20problem/ReadTLEFile